# A Problem with Solving a Recurrence relation

Tags: runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

I Hope someone Can help me with that:

- $T(1)=2$
- $T(n)=\left(T(\frac{n}{2})\right)^2\cdot2^n $

what is the runtime complexity of the algorithm (base 2)
Thanks a Lot!

Comment: T(2) = 16, T(4) = 2^12, T(8) = 2^32, T(16) = 2^80, T(32) = 2^192...

Answer (score 1):

Let $n:=2^m$ and take the logarithm.

$$\log(T(2^m))=2\log(T(2^{m-1}))+2^m$$

or

$$S(m)=2S(m-1)+2^m.$$

By educated guess (or alternative methods), the solution is

$$S(m)=(m+S_0)2^m$$

so that

$$T(n)=2^{(\log(n)+\log(T_1))n}=\left(T_1n\right)^n$$

Comment: So is the answer 2^O(nLogn) ?

Comment: @Bubi: this notation is not correct.